# selector this + option is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying that when the Change event is launched in a select with the same class as others, the value is retrieved, and if it is equal to one data then select another of the same select. My problem is in, I do not know how to create the selector. I've tried like this, but it does not work. Welcome all the answers

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
    var val = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    if( val === 2 ){
      $(this + 'option[value="3"]').prop('selected',true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="2">Val 2</option>
  <option value="3">Val 3</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="2">Val 2</option>
  <option value="3">Val 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that ... no, that won't work. In the event callback, `this` is bound to the element. You can't just append a string to that; it fundamentally doesn't make sense. Use `$(this).find("option[value='3']")`

Comment: You can simple do `$(this).val('3')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this` keyword to get `select` element and then use `find` method to get desired option. You cannot use this like you did in your example. Try running `this + 'option[value="3"]'` in your console - it will output `"[object Window]option[value=\"3\"]"`, which is not a selector you wanted.

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
    var val = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    if( val === 2 ){
      $(this).find("option[value='3']").prop('selected',true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="2">Val 2</option>
  <option value="3">Val 3</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="2">Val 2</option>
  <option value="3">Val 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.sel > option').click(function(e){
    var = trueVal = "";
    var selectedVal = $(e.target).attr('value');
    if(selectedVal == '1'){
        trueVal = '2';
    } else if(selectedVal == '2'){
        trueVal = '3';
    }
    return trueVal;
    console.log(trueVal);
   // Do whatever you want with trueValue
});
```